# Chrome CSS issue with absolute positioned input elements inside of relative parents (Chrome 32.0.1700.77) right: 0 not working

Tags: css, google-chrome

I just noticed this issue after an auto update to Chrome 32.0.1700.77. I can set `top`, `left`, and `bottom` in an absolutely-positioned input element, however `right: 0` is ignored. Here's my code:

```
<div id="content">
    <input type="search"/>
</div>

#content {
    position: relative;
    top: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: gray;
}

#content input[type="search"] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    /* width 100%; */
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hAuSL/4/

It was working as expected before the update. I also see this issue in Firefox (26.0) but not in Opera (18.0.1284.68) or Safari (7.0.1 (9537.73.11)).

I can work around it by adding `width: 100%` to the input element style; but I'm wondering, is there something wrong with the CSS or is this a browser issue?

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Comment: Sounds like a legit bug to report.

Comment: Passing observation: bear in mind that // isn't a comment in CSS, and can cause some odd problems in itself...

Comment: But yes, I'd agree that this is a bug (and will probably break quite a few things, since I've seen this technique used quite a lot since the [A List Apart article on it](http://alistapart.com/article/conflictingabsolutepositions) came out. (Comment #22 on that article references the bit of the spec that says this should work.)

Comment: @MattGibson, thanks; I'm too accustomed to Sass. Fixed in original question. Just to note, the previous bit, `// width: 100%;` is not related to the issue at hand.

Comment: Since `div#content` is a block element, how it works if you remove the redundant `width:100%` from `#content`? Should have no effect, but just a thought.

Comment: @t.888 I am talking about the first `width:100%` declared in `#content`.

Comment: @JoseRuiSantos, in the provided [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hAuSL/2/) removing the `width: 100%` line from the `#content` element appears to make no difference whatsoever in Chrome.

Comment: @t.888 That's what I thought. Indeed it sounds like a bug

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not a bug, see how absolutely positioned replaced elements' width is computed:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-replaced-width

> The used value of 'width' is determined as for inline replaced elements.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-replaced-width

> if 'width' has a computed value of 'auto', and the element has an intrinsic width, then that intrinsic width is the used value of 'width'.

At this point the element dimensions are over-constrained (it has `width`, `left` and `right`) so the following rule applies:

> ignore the value for either 'left' (in case the 'direction' property of the containing block is 'rtl') or 'right' (in case 'direction' is 'ltr') and solve for that value.

It's what you see, right is ignored. As `<input>` always have a default width you should set yours (100% in this case) and remove the `right` rule.

---

For a more generic solution you can wrap the replaced element in any non-replaced element (like a `<div>`) which will be absolutely positioned with `left` and `right`, then you can set the wanted width for the other element (be careful, if the box-model is `content-width` the `width` value will be added to any padding and border).

See http://jsfiddle.net/2UaYm/ for example.

Comment: Even without `width: 100%` in the `#content` element the behavior appears the same in the given [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hAuSL/2/). Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: No, `width: 100%;` is more than useless on block-level non-replaced elements, you should remove it anyways (see http://www.impressivewebs.com/width-100-percent-css/). I meant `width: 100%;` on `<input>`.

Comment: @t.888 What if `right:0` and `width:auto` is used for `input`?

Comment: `width: 100%` removed from original question text. Here's a new Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hAuSL/4/. The behavior is the same.

Comment: `width: auto` for input element: same behavior.

Comment: Can you please read my answer instead of trying hazardous pieces of CSS?

Comment: @MatTheCat I understand your answer, but how come it works for other browsers. Are all browsers doing it wrong and this latest Chrome fixed this w3 recommendation?

Comment: Not all browsers have it wrong (just tested in Firefox 26), but what you see now isn't a bug. What you saw before was.

Comment: As it stands, Opera and Safari honor setting all four edges for absolutely positioned elements but Chrome and Firefox do not. Setting `width: 100%` in the absolutely positioned element is at least a work-around for the issue, except for not allowing an absolutely positioned right edge.

Comment: It's not a work-around as it's the right thing to do. *Replaced* elements always have a width and according to the W3C you cannot override it with `left` and `right`.

Comment: How might one go about setting the right edge to 10px inset from its parent element, or 2px, or 0px (except for setting a percentile scale)? Absolute positioning implies absolute inputs, putatively on all four edges. Can you provide a fiddle that allows for the absolute positioning of all four edges in current browsers?

Comment: Ah! Interesting. I'd not considered the replaced element factor when I was thinking about this earlier on. For some reason `input`s aren't in my head as replaced elements.

Comment: (And here's one of the Mozilla bug reports where someone explains that it's actually the correct behaviour: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=416634 )

Comment: I'm gathering that there's no way to absolutely position the right edge of an input element in the way outlined in the original question, except for perhaps embedding it into another div.

Comment: `<div>`'s width can be computed as `auto` so you can indeed set its dimension with `left` and `right` and append it your `<input>` with 100% width (beware of the box model).

Comment: @MatTheCat, I'll go ahead and accept your answer if you can append a solution that shows the proper way to absolutely position an input element in the given context. `width: 100%` by itself works great unless somebody needs to have another value for `right` or `left` besides zero. Personally I think that enclosing the input element in an absolutely positioned `div` tag is the way to go, since the input element's width can be set to `100%` inside the inner div, which can itself be absolutely positioned with any value for each side. That's how I ended up solving it anyway.

Comment: Good point about the box model too. I think that `box-sizing: border-box` might possibly help there.